# "PCM only for now" error, called at ./Data/WAVE.hs:127:11 in WAVE-0.1.3

Tags: haskell, audio, wav

I am attempting to play a .wav file, and am trying Hackage's [WAVE audio file IO library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/WAVE) to do so.

I generated a recording `myrecording.wav` and in the same directory placed this simple program:

```
module PlayWave where

import Data.WAVE

path :: String
path = "myrecording.wav"

main = do
  getWAVEFile path
```

I try to run it with `$ runhaskell PlayWav.hs` and get the following error:

```
$ runhaskell PlayWav.hs 
PlayWav.hs: PCM only for now
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at ./Data/WAVE.hs:127:11 in WAVE-0.1.3-EDUsomPiULdBJaA1HF9vpg:Data.WAVE
```

The reported error corresponds to line 127 of [this](https://github.com/BartMassey/wave/blob/8a62127ffe684066003feb2fc1a52ae25a93d509/Data/WAVE.hs) file in WAVE's source code.
I see the error case there but do not understand why my code could be causing that failure.

Am on macOS Sierra 10.12.4

Comment: It looks like the library is incomplete and you tried to play an unimplemented format. Try finding alternatives.

Comment: Right. AFAIK, [`hsndfile-storablevector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsndfile-storablevector) is the most usable audio-file loader at the moment. There's [work on progress](https://github.com/acowley/ffmpeg-light/issues/21) on the much more powerful ffmpeg's bindings. A native Haskell solution like `WAVE` is may sure be appealing, but it's somewhat infeasible due to the vast number of different audio formats around.

Comment: The `file` command will give you some hints on the type of WAV file you have. There's also a `mediainfo` command on some systems.

Comment: Also the WAVE library doesn't "play" a .wav file as OP intended. It is only meant for parsing and writing .wav files not playing them, you will need another library for that: [SDL-mixer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/SDL-mixer-0.6.2.0) is one of several libraries that can play a sound file.